# Trying to open display device handle to change brightness on Windows XP using C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, monitor

I am trying to write a C++/WinAPI code to change a monitor brightness. The code must be compatible with Windows XP so I can't use APIs like SetMonitorBrightness. So I thought to try out [IOCTL_VIDEO_SET_DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372704.aspx) but I can't seem to even get a device handle.

```
HANDLE hDevice = ::CreateFile(_T("\\\\.\\LCD"),
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    0, NULL);
if(hDevice != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    //Do work here

    ::CloseHandle(hDevice);
}
else
{
    nOSErr = ::GetLastError();
    //Get code 2
}
```

I tried various combinations of GENERIC_READ, GENERIC_WRITE and FILE_SHARE_READ, FILE_SHARE_WRITE flags but I always get error code 2 when CreateFile is called.

So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I get a valid handle when I try.

Comment: I just tried it on Windows Vista (laptop) and got a valid handle as well. Any idea why it doesn't work on my Windows 7 machine?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a Windows 7 machine to try; I guess I could spin up a Windows 8 Preview VM but I would have to load stuff up on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that not all devices support this API, right? Your laptop probably supports it because it allows software adjustment of its screen brightness, perhaps even with function keys on the keyboard. Your other machine (the one running Windows 7) probably doesn't support it, so calling `CreateHandle` with `\\\\.\\LCD` doesn't get you anything useful. It has nothing to do with the operating system and everything to do with the hardware and/or the video drivers.

Comment: Good point, thanks. What is interesting is that SetMonitorBrightness seems to change monitor brightness on this Windows 7 machine (where "\\.\LCD" device failes) but where the "\\.\LCD" device succeeds on Windows Vista, SetMonitorBrightness fails with an error code ERROR_GRAPHICS_I2C_ERROR_TRANSMITTING_DATA.

Comment: All I'm looking for is a reliable way to change monitor brightness that is supported down to Windows XP SP3. Any idea what that could be?

Comment: Did you find out a solution for your problem?

Comment: This is because there are two different APIs for different types of devices.
SetMonitorBrightness() is for externally connected (e.g. HDMI) monitors that support the DDC/CI protocol.
Whereas the DeviceIoControl() function only works with internal (e.g. laptop) screens - that you can normally control with the control panel power menu.
You should be able to open a file handle to both kinds, if you use their full DOS path name, which you can get from the DeviceID in EnumDisplayDevicesW() with EDD_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_NAME set.